# Change value of label defined in bss section with "equ" in x86 assembly

Tags: assembly, x86, base64, x86-64

Hello I am currently working on a base64encoder written in x86 assembly. I got most of it done now, but I still got a small problem.

I defined an output buffer length of 4 because normally 4 bytes of ascii chars are written.

```
SECTION .bss
    OutputBufLen: equ 4
```

So now if there is only one byte or two bytes of input read I only want to write two or three byte to stdout.

Is there a way I can change the value of `OutputBufLen`? I tried to do `mov [OutputBufLen], 3` but then I have to specify a size but with `byte` I think it seems to be too much. And `dec` also doesnt seem to work.

The write part:

```
printOutputBuf:
    mov rax, 1
    mov rdi, 1
    mov rsi, OutputBuf
    mov rdx, OutputBufLen
    syscall
```

Can you give me some tips? I'm sorry if I missed some important information but I'm pretty new to this.

Comment: Which assembler are you using?

Comment: No, `equ` is a compile time construct. Use a run-time variable instead, e.g. `OutputBufLen dq 4` and then access as `[OutputBufLen]`.

Comment: Note that the BSS section can only hold zero-initialized stuff, like `dq 0` or `resq 1` or `resb 8`.  Not `dq 4`.  If you want it static-initialized to `4` but then overwrite it later, it should be in `.data`.

Comment: But really, the total size of the buffer and the currently-in-use length are different things.  You want the buf length when you're reading new input into it, and you want the length of your last `read` (the return value) when you're going to loop over it or `write` it to another file descriptor.

Comment: @PeterCordes Yeah when I went to sleep yesterday I thought about that aswell but thank you!